# I'm using threading, so why get my gui all time frezzed O.o

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Oke i got the problem days ago and someone helped me with treading but my code was really ugly (im totaly new to coding) now i try to make it better and on an smarter way but now my gui get a frezze all time.
i tryed to do it on the way like my last code but it dosent work this time.
What have i to do this time i cant understand it but want understand it.
some Helpful Tips and tricks ?
Or better ways to do it smart, faster, and more powerfull, or mybae the gui more Beautyfule  ?

```
import time
import sys
from tkinter import *
import threading


root = Tk()

root.geometry("600x400")


global start
start = 1


def startUp():
    user_input()
    thr = threading.Thread(target=user_input)
    thr.start()



def user_input():
    global nameInput
    global start
    nameInput = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    start = 0
    if start < 1:
        while True:
            apex = ApexLegends("APIKey")
            player = apex.player(nameInput)
            print("Gesamt Kills: " + player.kills + "\n" + 'Gesamt Damage: ' + player.damage)
            time.sleep(3)
    else:
        print("stop")


anleitung=Label(text="Gib einen Spielernamen ein und drücke Start")
anleitung.pack()

textBox=Text(root, height=1, width=30)
textBox.pack()

startButton=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Start", command=lambda:startUp())
startButton.pack()
```

Comment: What is `ApexLegends`? Is it a class or a function? When you do `apex = ApexLegends("APIKey")`, does that take a long time (where "long" means "greater than 300ms or so)?

Comment: it is an access to a lib that was made for an easyer way to use the api of the Game Apex Legends

Comment: I still don't know what that means. Is it a class or a function call? Is it fast or slow? If it's fast, there's no reason to use threading.

Comment: i dont really know that look at this would it help to find it out ?
http://prntscr.com/n6hjig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def startUp():
    user_input()
    thr = threading.Thread(target=user_input)
    thr.start()
```

This doesn't look right. You're calling `user_input()` in both the main thread *and* the child thread. If you only want it to run in the child thread, don't call it that first time.

```
def startUp():
    thr = threading.Thread(target=user_input)
    thr.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter isn't designed to be accessed by more than one thread. Here is an excellent answer by one of the guys who has a very deep understainding of how tcl & tk works (the libraries that tkinter depends on), explaining why this is so.

[Callback to python function from Tkinter Tcl crashes in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767355/callback-to-python-function-from-tkinter-tcl-crashes-in-windows/38767665#38767665)

This is the first of the two paragraphs in that answer:

> Each Tcl interpreter object (i.e., the context that knows how to run a Tcl procedure) can only be safely used from the OS thread that creates it. This is because Tcl doesn't use a global interpreter lock like Python, and instead makes extensive use of thread-specific data to reduce the number of locks required internally. (Well-written Tcl code can take advantage of this to scale up very large on suitable hardware.)

Comment: Informative link. I was aware that modifying widgets from a different thread was a Bad Idea, but I wasn't sure whether a read-only operation like `Text.get` was dangerous. Danal doesn't seem to make a distinction between mutating and non-mutating, so I guess the prudent approach is to avoid both.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Trason I've played with your code and I suggest an oo approach.

In the code below I've try to adapt a functional script to your code.

First of all I've use a variable as

> self.nameInput = tk.IntVar()

to store the user input on

> tk.Entry(w, bg='white', textvariable=self.nameInput).pack()

I've use an Entry widget instead of Text but it should be the same.

Furthermore I use a class to manage thread start and stop operation.

Look, I changed  your 'start' variable with 'check' because start is a reserved word

in python thread module.

I tried to recreate the functionality of your code.

Try to import and use your ApexLegends.

```
import tkinter as tk

import threading
import queue
import datetime
import time

class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue,nameInput):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.queue = queue
        self.nameInput = nameInput
        self.check = True

    def stop(self):
        self.check = False

    def run(self):

        while self.check:
            # apex = ApexLegends("APIKey")
            #player = apex.player(self.nameInput.get())
            x = "Gesamt Kills: " + "player.kills" + "\n" + 'Gesamt Damage: ' + "player.damage"+ "\n"
            s = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            msg = "{} datetime: {} nameInput {}".format(x,s,self.nameInput.get())
            time.sleep(3)
            self.queue.put(msg)


class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,):

        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello World")
        self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.on_close)

        self.queue = queue.Queue()

        self.my_thread = None
        self.nameInput = tk.IntVar()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.f = tk.Frame()

        w = tk.Frame()

        tk.Label(w, text = "Gib einen Spielernamen ein und drücke Start").pack()
        tk.Entry(w, bg='white', textvariable=self.nameInput).pack()

        w.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

        w = tk.Frame()

        tk.Button(w, text="Start", command=self.startUp).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Stop", command=self.stop_thread).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
        self.f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

    def startUp(self):

        if (threading.active_count()!=0):

            self.my_thread = MyThread(self.queue,self.nameInput)
            self.my_thread.start()
            self.periodiccall()

    def stop_thread(self):

     if(threading.active_count()!=1):
         self.my_thread.stop()


    def periodiccall(self):

        self.checkqueue()
        if self.my_thread.is_alive():
            self.after(1, self.periodiccall)
        else:
            pass

    def checkqueue(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                ret = self.queue.get(0)
                msg = "%s"%(ret)
                print(msg)
            except queue.Empty:
                pass                    

    def on_close(self):
        if(threading.active_count()!=0):
            if self.my_thread is not None:
                self.my_thread.stop()

        self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```