# Is tkinter's `after` method thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, thread-safety

Since tkinter isn't thread-safe, I often see people use the `after` method to queue some code for execution in the main thread. Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread

def change_title():
    root.after(0, root.title, 'foo')

root = tk.Tk()
Thread(name='worker', target=change_title).start()
root.mainloop()
```

So instead of executing `root.title('foo')` directly in the `worker` thread, we queue it with `root.after` and let the main thread execute it. But isn't calling `root.after` just as bad as calling `root.title`? Is `root.after` thread-safe?

Comment: I guess root.after adds a task in a queue, from which the tasks are executed sequentially by root.mainloop()

Comment: Well `after()` is simply tkinter's way of managing events to be run after a specific time. It is no different than just calling the function/command directly but simply done at a later time. I do not believe it has any interaction with the threaded task it is calling. I don't work with the global namespace from within a thread like this though so I am not sure. I typically pass anything that needs to be updated to the thread and then make changes from there.

Comment: If ***"Since tkinter isn't thread-safe!"*** is `True` then ***"Is root.after thread-safe?"*** can't be `True`?

Comment: @Mike-SMT I don't think this is true: _"It is no different than just calling the function/command directly but simply done at a later time. "_. It's a significant difference, in that calling `after` simply adds something to a queue, it doesn't touch the internal widget objects.

Comment: Have you read the following answer? It is probably the most authoritative answer on threading, given that it was written by one of the Tcl developers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38767665/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley I hadn't seen that, thanks. Sounds like a "no" to me.

Comment: @BryanOakley That makes sense.  So by assigning an event to occur say to `root` then does that mean the event is actually occurring in the main thread and has no issues from being assigned during a threaded function?

Comment: @Mike-SMT: Assuming that mainloop pulls the item off of the queue, it will be run in whatever thread `mainloop` is running in -- which is presumably the main thread. However, if you call `update` from some other thread, it will probably be run in that thread.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh ok good to know. If you run `update()` from another thread that sounds like it could cause some issues.

Answer (score 3):

`after` is thread-safe because it is implemented in terms of `call` which is generally thread-safe according to the CPython [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5d6aba318ead9cc756ba750a70da41f5def3f8f/Modules/_tkinter.c#L1472-L1555) if CPython and Tcl were built with thread support (the most common case). This means quite a large footprint of `tkinter` methods are thread-safe, but not all (particularly `eval`).

If you call `after` (or `call`) from some other CPython thread, it will actually send a thread-safe message to the main thread (with the Tcl interpreter) to actually interact with the Tcl API and run the command in the main thread.