# Strange behaviour of tkinter when using multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

When a new thread destroys a tkinter Tk object whose mainloop is in the main thread, the new thread seems to get stuck and never continues or completes. Why does this happen? The code below shows an example of what I mean:

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import *
import time

win = Tk()


def exit_after_time():
    time.sleep(2)
    win.destroy()


thread = Thread(target=exit_after_time)
thread.start()

win.mainloop()
print("mainloop quit")
thread.join()
print("thread joined")
```

When this is run, the mainloop is quit after 2 seconds, but the thread is never joined. At the moment I'm just working around this by making the thread a daemon and not waiting for it to finish, but I'd like to know what's actually going on.

Comment: From someone who actually works on the underlying tcl code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38767665/7432

Comment: ***working around this by making the thread a daemon***: This is not a workaround, it's mandatory.

Comment: You don't need to join the thread as it should be terminated after destroying the root window.