# Python Tkinter: Referencing a slider value in multiple threads results in error

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I created a custom tkinter widget class which has (among other things) a slider. The below methods run_control_thread and control_loop are methods within said class. They run a thread that sends a command to a motor when a button (also a "child" of my widget class) is pressed. This works fine when only one widget is controlling a motor, but if there are multiple widgets controlling (different) motors, an error pops up when trying to run self.slider.get(), seen in the run_control_thread method. Instead of getting the value of the slider, it gets an exception. I'm quite new to Python, Tkinter, and Stack Overflow, so any help would be appreciated!

```
    def run_control_thread(self):
        global HTTP, command
        print("running")
        def run_thread():
            global HTTP, command
            current_device = CANDeviceDict[self.current_chosen]
            while(self.control_loop_enabled == True):
                demand = self.slider.get()
                HTTP.send_command(command.control(current_device.model, current_device.id, demand, False, False, 
                                  self.control_mode_value(), 0, 0, False, False))
                time.sleep(0.028)
        control_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_thread)
        control_thread.start()

    def control_loop(self):
        global HTTP, selected_device, command
        if HTTP != None and command != None and selected_device != None:
            if (self.control_loop_enabled):
                self.control_loop_enabled = False
                self.enable_control.config(text="Enable Control")
                self.slider.set(0)
            else:
                self.control_loop_enabled = True
                self.enable_control.config(text="Disable Control")
            self.run_control_thread()
```

The errors:

```
>Exception in thread Thread-4"
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3457, in get
    return self.tk.getint(value)
    _tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "expected integer but got "0.00""
    <class 'tkinter.Scale'>

>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    demand = self.slider.get()
    File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3460, in get
    return self.tk.getdouble(value)
    <class 'tkinter.Scale'>
    _tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got "expected integer but got "0.00""
```

Comment: Tkinter isn't thread-safe. All access to tkinter widgets needs to be in a single thread. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767355/callback-to-python-function-from-tkinter-tcl-crashes-in-windows/38767665#38767665) from one of the developers on the tcl/tk project.