# While loop is too slow in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop

When I create a while loop in tkinter, it runs too slow.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

root = Tk()

line = 1
col = 0
loop_count = 1

def highlight_one_by_one():
    global col , loop_count
    while True:
        text.tag_add("highlight" , f"{line}.{col}" , f"{line}.{col + 1}")
        text.tag_config("highlight" , foreground = "yellow" , background = "blue")
        col += 1
        loop_count += 1
        if loop_count >= len(text.get(1.0 , END)):
            print("done")
            break

text = Text(root, width = 69 , height = 25 , font = "Consolas 14")
text.grid(row=0 , column = 0)

highlight_button = Button(root, text = "Highlight all letters one by one" , command = lambda: threading.Thread(target=highlight_one_by_one , daemon=True).start())
highlight_button.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , pady = 5)

text.insert(END , "This is a text widget\t\t"*500)

mainloop()
```

Here, I have created a program where tkinter will highlight all the letters in the text widget one by one. But the problem is that the loop is too slow. It takes almost 30 seconds to highlight all the letters in the text widget. When I add a scrollbar to the text widget, the loop becomes even slower than before. What I want is to speed up the loop so that this loop can highlight all the letters in less than a second.

I know I could have used `text.tag_add("highlight" , 1.0 , END)` , but I didn't do that because in my other program, I have written some code where only specific letters will get highlighted.

I searched all over the internet regarding this issue, but couldn't find any solution.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: It's an infinite loop, of course it will take infinite time...

Comment: So, why do you use a `Thread` to do the work? I didn't think that `tkinter` would work when widgets were being modified in a different thread.

Comment: @quamrana , I am using thread so that the GUI does not freeze while the loop is running.

Comment: Ok, so normally with GUIs you wouldn't use long running loops. But when you really need one, then maybe a `Thread` will work, but then you shouldn't be modifying the GUI from the new thread. And there are ways round that, but seeing as how you want the loop to run fast, have you tried *not* using a thread and getting the button to call the function directly?

Comment: Oh, I tried it and it makes the loop faster, but it still freezes the GUI and takes some time to highlight all the text. But I don't want that, as our app should not freeze suddenly when a user is working with it. Is there any way to shorten this time period?

Comment: So your loop must be taking some time to complete. Is there a way to do the `tag_add()` in a single call?

Comment: I don't think so, as we need to keep adding a new tag for each letter in the text widget.

Comment: calling `.get(1.0, END)` in the loop is doing a lot of unnecessary work. You aren't adding data while the loop is running so the length will never change. The text widget has methods for efficiently compare text indices. You also don't need to keep configuring the same tag over and over. You just have to configure it once.

Comment: I don't know how `tag_add` works, but looking at the parameters: `f"{line}.{col}" , f"{line}.{col + 1}"` it looks like you specify a start and end. What if it were: `f"{line}.{col}" , f"{line}.{col + n}"` where `n` is the length of the text?

Comment: Here is additional information about tkinter and threads, from one of the people who works on the underlying tk code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38767665/7432

Comment: @quamrana: yes, tkinter has the way to do index expressions like "1.0+1character".

Comment: @BryanOakley , I understood how threads work in detail, but even if I don't create a separate thread and use a single thread, tkinter is freezing the window and taking time to show the output I need. Is there any way to make the loop faster and reduce the time taken to show the output?

Comment: I doubt there's any way to speed this up significantly. You might be able to do several hundred characters a second, but I doubt much more than that. This is just not something tkinter is optimized for. If you're expecting the display to be updated after every character it is inherently going to be slow because screen updates are relatively slow. However, if you defer the screen update until all of the characters have been marked, you can do a few thousand per second.

Comment: It would help if you explained what you're trying to accomplish. If you're wanting to add the "highlight" tag to every character, that can be done in a single statement. If you need it added one character at a time, or one line at a time, that will impact the choice of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been experimenting and this works faster:

```py
from tkinter import *
import threading

root = Tk()

line = 1
col = 0
loop_count = 1

def highlight_at_once():
    end = len(text.get(1.0 , END))
    col = 0
    text.tag_add("highlight" , f"{line}.{col}" , f"{line}.{col + end}")
    text.tag_config("highlight" , foreground = "yellow" , background = "blue")

def highlight_one_by_one():
    global col , loop_count
    end = len(text.get(1.0 , END))
    while True:
        text.tag_add("highlight" , f"{line}.{col}" , f"{line}.{col + 1}")
        
        col += 1
        loop_count += 1
        if loop_count >= end:
            print("done")
            break
    text.tag_config("highlight" , foreground = "yellow" , background = "blue")

text = Text(root, width = 69 , height = 25 , font = "Consolas 14")
text.grid(row=0 , column = 0)

highlight_button = Button(root, text = "Highlight all letters one by one" , command = lambda: threading.Thread(target=highlight_one_by_one , daemon=True).start())
#highlight_button = Button(root, text = "Highlight all letters one by one" , command = highlight_at_once)
highlight_button.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , pady = 5)

text.insert(END , "This is a text widget\t\t"*500)

mainloop()
```

Comment: pendantically speaking, `1.0` needs to be `"1.0"` - text indexes are strings, not floating point numbers. But yes, highlighting groups of characters will be much, much faster than doing one at a time.